# Clear any Previous error message in Jquery CodeIgniter

Tags: php, jquery, codeigniter, validation

I am posting this question after searching alot on google.I am posting my FORM on Jquery POST method and doing validation in codeigniter.

If a field is empty,it show me error message,BUT when i fill that field and click again,this time there is no error but it do not remove previous error message.
Here is my code

```
 var parameters = $("#frm_rexpert").serialize();
     var form = $("#frm_rexpert");
     $.post(siteurl+'/services/req_expert', parameters, function(data) {
        if (data.status == true) {
            //show success message
            $("#msg_exp").show();
            setTimeout(function() { $("#msg_exp").hide(); }, 5000);
        }else{
            $.each(data.errors, function(key, val) {

                $('[name="'+ key +'"]', form).after(val);

            })
        }
    }, "json");
```

On server side

```
       $this->form_validation->set_rules($rules);
        $this->form_validation->set_error_delimiters('<div class="error">', '</div>');
        if ($this->form_validation->run())
        {//do your code
        }else{
       $errors = array();
            // Loop through $_POST and get the keys
            foreach ($this->input->post() as $key => $value)
            {
                // Add the error message for this field
                $errors[$key] = form_error($key);
            }
            $response['errors'] = array_filter($errors); // Some might be empty
            $response['status'] = FALSE;
          }
     header('Content-type: application/json');
     exit(json_encode($response));
```

MY Question is "If there is no error,I need to clear all old error messages"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to clear the console, you just need to use `console.clear()` inside the success block. If you also want to erase all the things inserted by previous errors, you need to remove what is `after` each form input.
Something like this:

```
 $.post(siteurl+'/services/req_expert', parameters, function(data) {
    if (data.status == true) {
        $('.error', form).remove(); //removes previous errors' notices
        console.clear(); //clears the debug console
        //show success message
        $("#msg_exp").show();
        setTimeout(function() { $("#msg_exp").hide(); }, 5000);
    } ...
```

Edit: I changed the selector to match your elements with errors.

Answer (score 0):

See the code below. I have put my comments in all CAPS.

Description : You should have two different elements to show success and error message. Then you show error message when there is an error, for example empty field, and hide error message when successful, also show success message if you want. If you want to have more then one error message, for example if there are repeated errors and you want to stack error messages then you shouldn't be using id as the element selector, instead use class. Since id can not be assigned to more then one element in html. Use `$(".msg_exp").hide();` instead of `$("#msg_exp").hide();`

```
var parameters = $("#frm_rexpert").serialize();
     var form = $("#frm_rexpert");
     $.post(siteurl+'/services/req_expert', parameters, function(data) {
        if (data.status == true) {
            //SHOW SUCCESS MESSAGE AND HIDE ERROR MESSAGE.
            $("#msg_success").show();
            setTimeout(function() { $("#msg_error").hide(); }, 5000);
        }else{
            //SHOW ERROR MESSAGE.
            $("#msg_error").show();
            $.each(data.errors, function(key, val) {

                $('[name="'+ key +'"]', form).after(val);

            })
        }
    }, "json");
```

Comment: `#msg_success` and `#msg_error` are likely to be unique in the page and he's using classes to show the errors' messages, as you can see in his controller: `'<div class="error">`. The problem was that he didn't remove what he added with when `data.status` was not true... That's why I [suggested above](http://stackoverflow.com/a/32972696/1326147) to remove those `div.error`.